# Sampling From Erlang Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

I have k and λ given where λ is the average amount of events occurring within one hour. I must now obtain time intervals sampled from this distribution where the delay between the events occurring is in seconds. I know that the mean delay between two events is `k/λ` but I have no idea how to proceed from there.

Comment: For small $k$ / introductory usage, you may try to sum $k$ i.i.d. $\text{exp}(\lambda)$ to get the desired distribution. Otherwise you may try rejection sampling, or the method used in R: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/GammaDist.html

Comment: @BGM Ok I managed to use the code you supplied in the link; one question, do I need to make any adjustments to the  λ seeing it is given as (events / per hour) and the time intervals I need are in seconds.

Comment: Of course you may use a new $\lambda' = \frac {\lambda} {3600}$, or equivalently after sampling the random variable in hour, you multiply it by $3600$ to convert to second.